# Angular - diff in IE and Chrome

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

I have two button that are overlapping, and use ng-hide for the m with the same flag.
On Chrome it work perfectlly, but when I use IE 11, the icons are overlapping on page load.

I have two icons on in my search box:
[image]
[image]

And On IE11, when the page is loading:
[image]

The code is:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit" ng-show="vm.isSearchIconVisible" >
                <i class="iconMglass"></i>
 </button>
 <button type="reset" ng-show="!vm.isSearchIconVisible" class="clearTextButton" ng-click="vm.clearSearchText()">
                <span class="clearIcon">X</span>
 </button>
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-if`instead of `ng-show`.
The `ng-if` directive removes the content from the page and `ng-show`/`ng-hide` uses the CSS display property to hide content.

Not using CSS by changing to `ng-if` prevents these CSS problems. Although the `ng-if`creates a new `scope` but that impact is nothing.

```
 <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit" ng-if="vm.isSearchIconVisible" >
                <i class="iconMglass"></i>
 </button>
 <button type="reset" ng-if="!vm.isSearchIconVisible" class="clearTextButton" ng-click="vm.clearSearchText()">
                <span class="clearIcon">X</span>
 </button>
```

If you don't want to change to `ng-if`, then please share a working Plunkr/... so help you find your problem. Since it will be a `css`issue most likely.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that IE11 save cash with old code, CTR+R dident solve this problem.
In the IE11 option I revoce the option to save cash and it solve the problem, the new code appear.